# Expo av metadata doesn't work for android

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, expo

setOnMetadataUpdate doesn't support Android as per expo-av docs

[image]

Are there any workarounds to get the metadata in Android? I want to show the song's name and the author ...etc

Note: I tried it on iOS and it works properly. the problem happened only on Android.